# How do I get React Native NavigationBar to align correctly?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create a simple `NavigationBar` on react native but the alignment is not correct. The texts are not vertically aligned. I copy/pasted code from the [react-native examples](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/UIExplorer/js/Navigator/NavigationBarSample.js). If I open the `.xcodeproj` file and run it from xcode, everything seems to work correctly.

[image]

EDIT: Another image to show the right vertical spacing between the status bar and the navigation bar.

[image]

Comment: What is not being vertical align correctly ?  those `#825` ,`#658` and `next` seems to be as expected.

Comment: Added a second image to illustrate my point. The vertical spacing between the status bar and the title on the navigation bar is off.